# GetFilesByName in the Parent Folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a GoogleSheet and a template GoogleDoc in the same folder.
I'm trying to get a script in the Sheet to look in the Sheet's parent folder only, and search for the Template by name. I then want to duplicate the Template in the same folder.

I have many other copies with the same name as the Template in other folders, so the function must only search within the current folder.

This code will copy a template file from a grand-parent folder, and paste it in the grandparent folder..

```
function createNewGoogleDoc() {
   
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Magic Form')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const firstname = rows[2][6];
  const lastname = rows[3][6];

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Lead Client Flow Funnel Copy - Template').next();
  const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Lead Client Flow Funnel Copy - ${firstname} ${lastname}`);
```

How can I make it look just in the parent folder?

TIA!

Comment: Perhaps file.getParents().next().getFiles()?

Comment: I'm a noob to Scripts. How would that look as a full code solution?